# How can a hacker put malware on someone's PC when all precautions were taken?

Tags: malware

If someone buys a brand new PC with NO antivirus program, and:-

1. Never opens ANY emails/attachments
2. Never visits shady/malicious websites
3. Never downloads anything,
4. Never connects an infected removable drive to the PC.
5. Never clicks any advertisement

...but just browses YouTube, Wikipedia, and some other educational and trustable sites, how can a hacker put malware on their PC? Is there any way they can do that?

Not going to buy a new PC, but just trying to understand how hackers put malware on PC.

Comment: This is a bit like asking "If I buy a car and never go above the limit, nor through a red light, and always maintain it, how can I have an accident". The short answer is: once you connect your PC to the internet, anything is possible. Although a site is itself trustworthy, if they display external content (e.g. ads), it's exploitable. Is it probable? I wouldn't worry about it, but it's a nonzero possibility. It's theoretically possible – just as having a car accident; yet we still drive

Comment: @DigitalDracula I like the analogy, but I also mentioned that "no ads were clicked". That means no ads were clicked even from trustworthy sites. So never went to an "external content". Can you elaborate how merely connecting to the internet leaves someone vulnerable?

Comment: There are more ways than just those for a computer to get malware on it. Also critical: *keep your computer up to date*!

Comment: The only way to really be sure you won't get a virus is to not connect to the internet, not connect ANY devices or install any software. And even then some bad actor could still do it when you weren't paying attention ...

Comment: The computer (or device) doesn't even need to be connected to be compromised... Hardware backdoor exists. (Not to mention,  many of them are rootkits) If I would ref. 1 if the sources of this I would say; the Snowden Leaks. (I mean, really - the device I *suppose*  can get compromised without it being turned on, or even before one have "got" it from the online-store - quite hard to detect if we talk adv. Threat actors but, wanted to add this point

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A website does not need to be malicious. But the implementation of the website, the web server that hosts it, the OS that it runs on or the database may have vulnerabilities. Such a vulnerability may be exploited (by XSS, SQL injection, directory traversal etc.) and suddenly turns the trustworthy website into a malicious website without you (or anyone else) noticing it.

Comment: Just because a website is compromised doesn't mean your computer itself is compromised. Besides being extremely annoying and asking for escalated permissions, a website can't *do* anything unless you give it those escalated permissions, like the permission to install browser extensions. The web is sandboxed

Comment: @CarsonGraham: it seemed to me that OP was quite clear that it is possible to break out of the sandbox

Comment: @CarsonGraham - it should be sandboxed, but that is not 100% true...

Answer (score 5):

This question is difficult to answer since there can be numerous ways for your PC to get infected once it is connected to the internet.

One way you can end up with malware is (as @DigitalDracula pointed out) through untrusted content served through a trusted website. This usually in the form of ads. Even if you do not click on an ad, the untrusted content is still rendered in your web browser (assuming you do not use an adblocker), which means that a specially crafted ad by a malicious entity could exploit a vulnerability in your browser to execute code and install malware. The vulnerability exploited *could* be a zero day (a vulnerability the vendor is not yet aware of) but that is relatively unlikely. It would more likely be a known vulnerability which has been patched but is still exploitable on your system because you have not updated your browser.

Another way you could get infected is through a remote code execution vulnerability in your operating system. In this case, you could potentially get infected by simply connecting to a network which also has infected devices connected. Again, this vulnerability could be zero day (less likely) or a known vulnerability because your OS is not up to date. The (in)famous [WannaCry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WannaCry_ransomware_attack) worm exploited exactly this type of vulnerability to spread.

This is by no means an exhaustive list and there are other methods as well. The takeaway is that you should keep your system up to date to minimize the risk of infection. However, no computer connected to the internet is completely immune to attack.

Comment: In short: keep your software updated

Comment: @ConorMancone does more up to date also mean more secure? I doubt that no update ever introduces a new vulnerability.

Comment: @Haukinger Ofcourse updates do introduce new vulnerabilities sometimes. Occasionally they even [introduce backdoors](https://www.theregister.com/2020/12/14/solarwinds_fireeye_cozybear_us_government/). But updates include patches for any new **publicly known** vulnerabilities, which are the ones which are most commonly exploited (since they can be exploited by pretty much anyone), and therefore present the greatest risk to normal users

Comment: @nobody Indeed.

Comment: @Haukinger that's not the first time I've had that "gotcha" thrown at me, but just consider this: do you think you would be more secure by refusing all upgrades? :)

Comment: @ConorMancone would you rather fly with an airline/have your blood at a lab that always ever has the newest updates installed blindly and unquestioningly or with an airline/lab that checks that the update actually improves things and not introduce serious bugs? I doubt that normal users want to spend time/resources to have staging systems, and in my experience software for normal users is exceptionally bad (when compared to regulated stuff), so, for me, the resonable advice would be "update your software as late as possible" (to have others do the testing for you)

Comment: @Haukinger Its certainly your choice to update or not. Or if you want, you could just skip the quality/feature updates (which are the ones which usually introduce bugs) and just install the security updates. Since many non-techie users can't differentiate between the two, and sometimes security and feature updates are bundled together, the security advice is usually just to keep your system up-to-date. Personally, I would rather have a feature broken for a week or so rather than have my computer vulnerable to every script kiddie on the internet.