# Can a hacker hack my phone by not installing anything on my device?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, drive-by-download

I know that a device can be compromised by a drive-by download.

But could an attacker access my device without installing any malicious app? Can he access my camera by just executing a malicious JavaScript on a website?

Comment: Welcome to Sec.Exchange!   -   I mean,  we all have our own def. of the word "hack" but, because you're having the tag java script I suppose,  beef-xss (a tool in Kali) would have the potential to "hack"..

Comment: but that requires an bug/vulnerability in the browser right ?

Comment: No. It really depenends on your definition of "bug or vulnerability" for me, a browser that   (blindly) executes javascript - (**for me** - this is a vulnerability. It's the same as not having a Anti Virus on a system (Not exactly same, but I try to make the point that - It does not need to be a "unfixed" bug - (as in - the code, of the browser) to let a adversary gain control of the browser. (What I meant by the *executing javascript blindly* is, not having any kind of "on/off" to it - (like, the noscript addon) (or, same with any kind of malicious web-code)

Comment: ok so if i create a malicious js code which can access someone's camera does the browser blindly execute it and give them access ?

Comment: Depends on the browser.. Also depends on what you mean by creating a malicious js code (a file?) (A js 'script' that is on a website's source-code?) To answer the "blindly execute" part: It depends here, too. If your browser do indeed execute **all** javascript it sees, (without hesitation) same with a browser that **does that, but doesn't have a js protection (like noscript) installed**

Comment: The typical permissions on the browser and the phone's OS prevent this type of access. However, it used to be possibe a long time ago

Comment: @WilliamMartens so that makes browsers on android less secure ? since we cant install noscript extension/plugin on it .Also i would like to know do modern browsers analyize the script code before executing it ?

Comment: Thanks @schroeder for replying so even if the attacker executes a js script to access my camera he would have to make me give the permission right ?

Comment: That's for (**2**) other questions way off my area, but to try to summarize the two: I am not *entirely* sure that you *can't* install noscript (seems weird?) if you can't, you obviously (**really should**) be able to disable javascript in the browser.  + Side note of the permission Question above in your comment: I guess, if the browser is configured to ask first, yes (I think - I could be wrong here)

Comment: an up-to-date browser will prompt you for any access to your camera or location.  It'd still be possible to trick you into accepting that prompt, but javascript cannot access the prompt directly.  It's outside of the DOM.  Not sure about extension/browser add-ons... but that would be something that needed to be installed.

Comment: That requires chain of vulnerabilities. First, a vulnerability in browser that can compromise browser sandbox and execute arbitrary code in browser. Then using browser to exploit vulnerability in system. JavaScript cannot grant camera access directly. Browser prompts user to grant permission to the website and OS prompts user to grant camera access to the browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can a hacker put malware on someone's PC when all precautions were taken?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/242164/how-can-a-hacker-put-malware-on-someones-pc-when-all-precautions-were-taken)